# WebScanner Java Applet App Not working in chrome , NPAPI deprecated any solutions?

Tags: java, google-chrome, applet, java.util.scanner

Java Applet is not working in chrome, As NP-API is been depreciated is there any alternative solution, to load applet in browser and scanner is invoked to scan the file.

Advance Thanks, any help is appreciated.

[Scanner Applet application](https://github.com/ashishkataria/browserWebScanning)

Answer (score 0):

What's the chrome version??

Copy and paste "chrome://flags/#enable-npapi"  into your Chrome  browser and hit enter

Click the Enable link.

Quit your Chrome browser, then re-open it.

Comment: Hey Ashish Kataria, Thanks for Replying, i have try that but its still not working yaar, as google chrome  has stop supporting npapi, is there any alternative to run this application, please help me yar

Comment: After enabling chrome://flags/#enable-npapi,
At the very end of url bar, you will see a red cross image Plugin Blocked, just click on that and select allow plug-ins, it's working for me.. my chrome version is 43.0.

Comment: Note that this will work only in versions 43 and 44; 45 won't have this flag. So this answer won't work for long.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to run a Java applet within Chrome without NPAPI support. If you want to keep using an in-browser applet, you'll need to use another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Launch an application using **Java Web Start (JWS)**. Chrome supports it!